# Determine if a user has at least 5 receipts and 75% of their rating is higher than 9

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Receips. Receipts belong to users and can be rated by other users.
Now, i want to acknowledge users that have at least 5 receipts and 75% of their receipts have a rating >= 10

here is the table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE Receipts
{ 
      Id int identity primary key, 
      UserId int,
      Rating int,
);
```

one approach is to use a UNION

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Receipts WHERE Rating >= 10 AND UserId = @userId 
UNION SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Receipts WHERE UserId = @userId
```

And calculate the percentage and the minimum in code outside the query, but that seems not clever enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with getting all users that have any receipts:

```
SELECT
  UserId
FROM
  dbo.Receipts
GROUP BY
  UserId
;
```

Now you could use HAVING to filter out those with fewer than 5 receipts:

```
SELECT
  UserId
FROM
  dbo.Receipts
GROUP BY
  UserId
HAVING
  COUNT(*) >= 5
;
```

The other condition is trickier. First, this is how you would get the number of receipts that have a rating of at least 10:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN rating >= 10 THEN 1 END)
```

Now you can compare that to `COUNT(*) * 0.75`:

```
SELECT
  UserId
FROM
  dbo.Receipts
GROUP BY
  UserId
HAVING
  COUNT(*) >= 5
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN rating >= 10 THEN 1 END) >= COUNT(*) * 0.75
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT Tot.UserID, Tot.TotRes,  COALESCE(Good.GoodRes, 0) as GoodRes
FROM (SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) as TotRes FROM Receipts GROUP BY UserID) as Tot 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) as GoodRes FROM Receipts WHERE Rating > 9 GROUP BY UserID) as Good 
        ON Good.UserID = Tot.UserID
WHERE TotRes > 4 AND COALESCE(Good.GoodRes, 0)/TotRes >= 0.75
```